# For some reason, I get a message saying a grid is not nessecary and will not be used. Anyone know how to use a grid for only one box?

Tags: python, user-interface, guizero

Apparently, one can use different GUIzero layouts for different boxes, yet I am unable to leave my App undefined and use this code for a box:
`topBox = Box(win, layout="grid") firstNumHead = Text(win, text="First number", grid=[0,0]) firstNum = TextBox(win, grid=[1,0])`

It says the grid is unnecessary and will not be used, though it is defined in the box. What am I missing?

I've tried defining grid sizes for the box, nothing. I've also tried defining the App as a grid, but then that just messes up the box, as its supposed to stretch across the top, and cannot do so in a grid layout. I need a grid layout only for the box, yet I get only errors.

Comment: The grid layout for `topBox` is pointless, because that widget has no contents.  You're putting your other two widgets directly in the window, rather than into `topBox`.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you forget to place widgets in the box:

```
topBox = Box(win, layout=grid)
firstNumHead = Text(topBox, text="First number", grid=[0,0])
firstNum = TextBox(topBox, grid=[0,1])
```